# How to use pandas to fill a groupby data with all combination

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

| brand | media | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | M1 | 1 | 2 |
| B | M | 3 | 4 |
| B | M2 | 2 | 2 |

I have a dataset looks like this, the unique media column contains"M1,M2,M3", how to add all combination of brand and media and make the output like below:

| brand | media | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | M1 | 1 | 2 |
| A | M2 | 0 | 0 |
| A | M3 | 0 | 0 |
| B | M1 | 3 | 4 |
| B | M2 | 2 | 2 |
| B | M3 | 0 | 0 |

I've tried Iterate all over the excel, but is there other methods to achieve this?

Comment: df.groupby(["Brand","Media"],as_index=False).sum()